# Writing dynamic LINQ queries as closure methods

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, closures

I'm trying to write a C# repository with atomic contexts and feel like this is a perfect situation for the usage of a closure, but I can't quite grok how to get it done in C#. I have this as a main method in my repository:

```
...
    protected virtual IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _context.ObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
...
```

Meanwhile, I have derived classes with methods like:

```
...
    public IQueryable<Arc> ByRun(Run run)
    {
        IQueryable<Arc> query = from o in AsQueryable()
                                     from r in o.Runs
                                     where r.Id == run.Id
                                     select o;
        return query;
    }
...
```

and I want to change my query method to return IEnumerable and to dispose quickly of the context, so want to use (something like) this:

```
...
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable()
    {
        using (IContextUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
        {
            return unitOfWork.ObjectSet<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
...
```

The problem, of course, is that once the context is disposed, calling LINQ on the resulting IEnumerable set will fail. Thus, my thought is that I should bundle up the ByRun() method and pass it to AsEnumerable() to be used as a closure.

While not my original language style, I learned closures in Ruby. There, what I'm trying to do would look something like this mixed up pseudo-code:

```
ByRun(Run run)
  AsEnumerable do |query|
    from o in query
           from r in o.Runs
           where r.Id == run.Id
           select o;
  end
end
```

where the AsEnumerable method would open the context, perform the operation that was passed in, and return. I'm sure I can do this once I understand the syntax, so I'm looking for my desired AsEnumerable and ByRun methods implemented this way.

Comment: As an addendum, I realize that LINQ and many methods in the IQueryable interface are implemented using closures, I just can't get to the code to see the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have a wrapper on any query to ensure that `AsEnumerable` is called at the end and context is disposed just after the query?

If so (assuming that your base class is generic with T parameter), try this:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable(Func<ObjectSet<T>, IQueryable<T>> query)
{
    using (IContextUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
    {
        return query(unitOfWork.ObjectSet<T>()).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And usage example:

```
public IEnumerable<Arc> ByRun(Run run)
{
    return AsEnumerable(query => from o in query
                                 from r in o.Runs
                                 where r.Id == run.Id
                                 select o);
}
```

The parameter of `AsEnumerable` here is the lambda expression containing any delegate that takes `ObjectSet<T>` as the only parameter and returns `IQueryable<T>`. So it's logically equivalent to have the following code in the derived class:

```
public IEnumerable<Arc> ByRun(Run run)
{
    using (IContextUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
    {
        return (from o in unitOfWork.ObjectSet<T>()
                from r in o.Runs
                where r.Id == run.Id
                select o).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```